# Updating feature not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am hoping that you can give me a suggestion that I cannot figure out.  I am trying to create an update feature for a database I have created for a project.  I want it to be just like the insert and delete function that I have created but I am at a loss......
Here is what I have created.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<h1>Franchise Call Log</h1>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM caller_info");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Franchise</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Firstname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Lastname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Franchise'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?> 

</body>
</html> 

<h1>Insert a New Caller</h1>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
Franchise: <input type="text" name="franchise">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<html>
<body>

<h1>Delete a Caller</h1>
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<html>
<body>

<h1>Update a Caller</h1>
<form action="update.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
Franchise: <input type="text" name="franchise">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Your records have been updated</h1>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Caller_info SET Firstname = '$firstname' WHERE Lastname '$lastname'");

mysqli_close($con);
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing = sign in your update statement.

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Caller_info SET Firstname = '$firstname' WHERE Lastname '$lastname'");

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Caller_info SET Firstname = '$firstname' WHERE Lastname = '$lastname'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your database set up but targeting lastname in a database update is one of the bad practice because we do not know there are data with the same lastname. Use `Id's` instead.

On your code you had the `=` missing on your where statement. It should be,

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Caller_info SET Firstname = '$firstname' WHERE Lastname = '$lastname'");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The problem though is there is a disconnect somewhere.  I have it showing the first, last and franchise name but it is not giving me something to update.  Hope that makes sense?